# Django Rest Framework - detail page of @detail_route

Tags: django, routes, django-rest-framework, detailview

I am ussing @detail_route on my viewsets.ModelViewSet.

```
class CompanyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CompanySerializer

    @detail_route(methods=['get', ], permission_classes=[IsCompanyUserPermission, ])
    def accounts(self, request, pk):
    ...
    return Response(...)

# urls.py
router.register(r'companies', views.CompanyViewSet)
```

this code creates url:

```
/companies/
/companies/{id}
/companies/{id}/accounts
```

I dont know how to add route/view to detail account:

```
/companies/{id}/accounts/{id_account}
```

Is there any way to add route and views to handle this route ?

(the best option would be add this on CompanyViewSet)

Cheers,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DRF does not handle nested routes by itself, you may handle it by hand or use an extension, like [drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers), but its outdated.

My advice : don't fight the framework, DRF is not good at playing with url-nested resources, do it another way.

Comment: Funny that this is an accepted and upvoted answer...by just saying you should __do it another way__ but no other way is suggested

Comment: @surfer190 "handle it by hand" is an actual solution. "don't fight the framework" is an advice to avoid loosing days trying to make it automagic within a framework that don't have this feature. PS and most of all: that was the only answer till yesterday

Comment: My apologies if I came across as rude. So when you say handle by hand, you mean extending from `APIView` and creating the custom url.

Answer (score 5):

So avoid it when you can...but sometimes it makes sense to nest resources or methods

So for your case to handle both the `accounts/` url and `accounts/{account_id}` you define another detail route.

You have already defined the one for `accounts` so you just add another function with a different name and ensure to add the `url_path` so you can get the `account_id` variable.

```
        @detail_route(methods=['get', ], permission_classes=[IsCompanyUserPermission, ])
        def accounts(self, request, pk):
        ...
        return Response(...)

        @detail_route(methods=['get', ], permission_classes=[IsCompanyUserPermission, ], 
                      url_path='^queues/(?P<account_id>[0-9]+)')
        def account_detail(self, request, pk, account_id):
        ...
        return Response(...)
```

This answer took [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909343/django-rest-framework-query-parameters-in-detail-route) as a reference

Comment: Nice :), at the time of my own answer/struggling, `url_path` [did not exist](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/release-notes/#303). No time to test from now. OP feedback welcome !