# Django rest framework: query parameters in detail_route

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have following ViewSet:

```
class BookViewSet(DefaultsMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = Book.objects.all()
   serializer_class = BookSerializer

   @detail_route()
   def chapter(self, request,pk=None):
       queryset = Chapter.objects.filter(book__pk=pk)
       serializer = ChpaterSerializer(queryset,
                       context={'request':request},
                       many=True)
       return Response(serializer.data)
```

So the url "/book/{id}/chapter" is valid.
But I don't know how I can config the ViewSet to have a url like "/book/{id}/chapter/{id}".
Maybe answer is using **lookup_field** or **lookup_url_kwarg** but I can not find usage them in the detail_route case.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you can do this adding `url_path` in the `detail_route` like:

```
@detail_route(url_name='chapter', url_path='chapter/(?P<chapter_id>[0-9]+)')
def chapter(self, request, pk=None, chapter_id=None):
   queryset = Chapter.objects.filter(book__pk=pk)
   serializer = ChpaterSerializer(queryset,
                   context={'request':request},
                   many=True)
   return Response(serializer.data)
```

Note that the name of the url in the default router defaults to the `url_path` argument if it is provided. So the view name would inlcude the query parameter string. By specifying the `url_name` argument, you can simplify that. I would recommend to use the method name there, which is the default if `url_path` is not specified. With that, you can reverse the url with

```
reverse('book-chapter', kwargs={'pk': 1, 'chapter_id': 4})
```

Comment: Thank you. And how can be "chapter_id" optional?

Comment: @Beheshti You can do that adding another detail_route like: `@detail_route(url_path='chapter')` OR you could just use one detail_route like: `@detail_route(url_path='chapter')` and pass the `chapter_id` in the url like: `/book/{id}/chapter?chapter_id=123`

Comment: Using the first solution I got this error:"chapter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chapter_id'"!

Comment: @Beheshti use different names for functions like: `def chapter_list(self, request, pk=None)` and `def chapter_detail(self, request, pk=None, chapter_id=None)`

Comment: This seems to break the url name with the DefaultRouter

Answer (score 1):

1. For endpoint url as:  (using Django REST ViewSets)

> {mysite}/users/{pk}/password/{id}

for this to work in my viewsets i did:

```
class UsersViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


@detail_route(url_path='password')
def password(self, request,pk=None):
    return HttpResponse("Wow! It Works")
```

from above you can retrieve id from url via pk variable.

2. For EndPoint Url as

   > {mysite}/users/{pk}/password/{number}

Change the above password method to

```
@detail_route(url_path='password/(?P<number>[0-9]+)')
def password(self, request,pk=None, number=None):
    return HttpResponse("Wow! It Again Works")
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the 1st example fits the url. there is `id` being accessed/provided/defined?

Comment: @NirIzr These `detail_route` has been deprecated. [link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.8-announcement/#deprecations)